# Post Soap XML request using retrofit2 (Simple XML Framework deprecated)

Tags: android, xml, post, retrofit2

I have a requirement to send xml to server using retrofit2. I tried with Simple xml framework but now it is not deprecated. 
Is there any other way to do this?
Please let me know

Comment: depcrecated or not maintained any more?

Answer (score 0):

Deprecated doesn't mean non-functional. You're free to continue using it. If it currently works never update it!

One of the prominent contributor Jack Warthon recommended [tikxml](https://github.com/Tickaroo/tikxml). [ref: 
[git issue link thread](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2733)]. But again this opinion based and this question should be closed on that ground.